# Can I have a transparent background AND a reflection of the object below in eevee?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am trying to create a 3D animated element for a video, which would work best if I can have the object on a transparent background, yet still somehow render a reflection of it below. Specifically, a rotating 3D book that is supposed to have a reflection beneath it when composited with a 2D background.
Is this possible? I have been experimenting with lighting and reflection settings in eevee, but I haven't been able to resolve it, and the reflective qualities of the plane beneath the object are not showing in the 'render' shading. I may be looking at something that isn't workable, but if anyone has any ideas I am open to them.

Comment: What is the surface that you want the reflection on? Can you please add images? Even some kind of basic sketch will do.